# Rspec: tests in after block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, refactoring, capybara

I have a spec like this:

```
context 'index' do
  let!(:article) { create :article }
  subject { visit articles_path }

  specify do
    subject
    expect(page).to have_content(article.title)
  end
end
```

However when I try to refactor it like this, it says I have 0 examples:

```
context 'index' do
  let!(:article) { create :article }
  subject { visit articles_path }

  context do
    after { expect(page).to have_content(article.title) }
  end

  context do
    before { login_as :user }
    after { expect(page).to have_content(article.comment) }
  end

  context do
    after {}
  end

end
```

Shouldn't it be running `subject` and then the `after` hook? I am pretty sure I have used this setup before.

Please tell me how to correctly refactor this. Thanks.

**Update**
Could do it like this, but I don't really like it:

```
subject do
  visit articles_path
  page
end

specify do
  expect(subject).to have_content(article.title)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

'after' block is normally used to do something after the test example has been executed. In your second example you have no test executed prior to the 'after' block

I would refactor your code like this

```
context 'index' do
  let!(:article) { create :article }
  visit articles_path
  expect(page).to_not have_content(category.title)
end
```

**edit**

```
context 'index' do
  let!(:article) { create :article }

  before do
    visit articles_path 
  end

  context do
    it "displays article's title" do
      expect(page).to have_content(article.title)
    end
  end

  context do
    before { login_as :user }
    it "displays article's comments" do
      expect(page).to have_content(article.comment)
    end
  end

  context do
    #another test
  end
end
```

Comment: The thing is I have more contexts further down the line that share the same `let!/visit` shared context. I thought I could do the actual testing in `context 'other' do after { expect }; end`

Comment: Please see my edited solution, I don't know why you are trying to put the verification code inside the after block.

Comment: In that case `before { login_as :user }` will be executed after `before { visit articles_path }` and to make your example work I would have to have `before { login_as :user; visit articles_path }` in the `context` block.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me from you refactoring attempt that there's a bit of confusion.

First, the reason why you were seeing `0 examples, 0 failures` is because there is no subject invocation in your tests. Think about it like this:

```
subject { visit articles_path }

it 'has a nice title' do
  subject
  expect(page).to have_content(article.title)
end

it 'has a nice comment' do
  subject
  expect(page).to have_content(article.comment)
end
```

In order for your expectations to work you need to call the subject. In fact you could have even avoided using a subject by explicitly writing in your `it/specify` blocks  `visit articles_path`

```
it 'has a nice title' do
  visit articles_path
  expect(page).to have_content(article.title)
end

it 'has a nice comment' do
  visit articles_path
  expect(page).to have_content(article.comment)
end
```

**Tests that share the same subject can be dried up using `subject { ... }`.**

Second, don't confuse `context` blocks with `specify/it` blocks(remember they're aliased).
A `context` is a way to make your tests more understandable by separating different results for the test.

```
subject { visit articles_path }

context 'user is logged in' do
  it 'displays article's title' do
    login_as :user
    subject

    expect(page).to have_content(article.title)
  end

  it 'displays article's title' do
    login_as :user
    subject

    expect(page).to have_content(article.comment)
  end
end

context 'user not logged in' do
  it 'displays article's comments' do
    subject

    expect(page).to have_content('Log in')
  end
end
```

You can have different expectations, it/specify blocks in the same context. 
**Use different context to specify different behaviour of the same functionality.**

Finally last step. Group shared functionality in a `before` block. In our example:

```
subject { visit articles_path }

before do
  subject
end

context 'user is logged in' do

  before do
    login_as :user
  end

  it 'displays article's title' do
    expect(page).to have_content(article.title)
  end

  it 'displays article's title' do
    expect(page).to have_content(article.comment)
  end
end

context 'user not logged in' do
  it 'displays article's comments' do
    expect(page).to have_content('Log in')
  end
end
```

As you can see, the two contexts run the subject but only the first content logs the user in to test the article page whereas the second context don't.
I hope this was useful.

Keep testing and soon it will become a matter of habit and you will be writing tests much easily.